# Need to update over 300 custom objects and disable "enableSearch"

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, update, global-search

I need to update about 350 custom objects and remove the flag for "enableSearch".
We do not want users to search these objects so they will not get confused with the primary data points.
I tried to use SOQL Query, but could not identify the object for Custom Object permissions.
How can we accomplish this?

Thank you,
~Joe

Comment: [metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) `CustomObject`

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of approaches here:

### Metadata API (Programmatic)

- Use the metadata API to first do a Describe to get a list of all the objects.
- Then, per object, fetch the [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) metadata. Modify the `enableSearch` property to false.  Use the API to deploy the changes back to the org

Note this can be done in APEX using the [Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) or from a REST client of your own making

### Metadata API (text editor)

- Use the Metadata API (such as via Workbench or your IDE) and retrieve all the custom objects.  Explode the ZIP (if using Workbench), files will be already exploded in your IDE
- Use your IDE or text editor to mass change the `enableSearch` property in the relevant `CustomObject`
- Redeploy the changed `CustomObject` back to your org using Workbench (rezipping) or your IDE